# ¿Cómo multiplicar una lista por un entero?

Tags: java

¿Cómo escribir un método mult tomando en los parámetros un entero y una lista de enteros y devolviendo una nueva lista de enteros donde todos los valores se multiplican por el primer argumento (coeficiente)?

Intente lo siguiente :

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Mult{
    static List mult(int coef, List<Integer> l){

        int array[] = new int[l.length];

        for( int i = 0; i < l.length; i++){
            array[i] = l[i] * coef;
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> listOfIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfIntegers.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,4,2,7,5));
        new_list = mult(2,listOfIntegers);
    }
}
```

Pero me devuelve :

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Julien\TD7_iterators>javac Mult.java
Mult.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
            int array[] = new int[l.length];
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable length
  location: variable l of type List<Integer>
Mult.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                for( int i = 0; i < l.length; i++){
                                     ^
  symbol:   variable length
  location: variable l of type List<Integer>
Mult.java:10: error: array required, but List<Integer> found
                        array[i] = l[i] * coef;
                                    ^
Mult.java:12: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to List
                return array;
                       ^
Mult.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
                listOfIntegers.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,4,2,7,5));
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class Mult
Mult.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
                new_list = mult(2,listOfIntegers);
                ^
  symbol:   variable new_list
  location: class Mult
6 errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays; //usas esta clase, falta importarla o usar su nombre completo

public class Mult{
    static List mult(int coef, List<Integer> l){

        int array[] = new int[l.size()]; ///es l.size() en lugar e l.length

    for( int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++){  //igual, size() en lugar de length
        array[i] = l.get(i) * coef;  //es l.get(i) en lugar de l[i]
    }
    //return arrays; //aquí retornas un array, necesitar retornar una lista:
    return Arrays.asList(array);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> listOfIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfIntegers.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,4,2,7,5)); 
    List new_list = mult(2,listOfIntegers); //faltaba agregar el tipo de variable new_list
}
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ¿Sabe cómo puedo modificar su implementación para que no tenga que asignar una nueva lista, sino que utilice el principio de una vista (con `AbstractList`), en forma de una clase anónima?

Comment: Si quieres retornar una Lista, creo que esa es la forma más sencilla. También pudiera retornar el arreglo en lugar de la lista. Osea el array[]

Answer (score 2):

El error que te sale es por que haces `l.length` que no existe ya que los objetos `list` usan `size()`

¿Para que transformar el list en un array? puedes recorrer la lista sin realizar ninguna transformación.

```
static void mult(int coef, List<Integer> l){
    for( int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++){
        l.set(i,l.get(i)*coef));
    }      
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<Integer> listOfIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
  listOfIntegers.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,4,2,7,5)); 
  mult(2,listOfIntegers); //faltaba agregar el tipo de variable new_list
}
```

Como volvemos a setear los valores de la lista, y esta no cambia, ni siquiera es necesario que el método `mult` devuelva una lista. Después de ejecutar el método, tu variable `listOfIntegers` tendrá el resultado final.

Answer (score 0):

al parecer es por que tu parametro es coef y lo estas multiplicando con coeff

```
static List mult(int coef, List<Integer> l)//en tu metodo tu parametro esta como coef

    array[i] = l[i] * coeff;//tu parametro es coef
```

espero que esto resuelva tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Mult{
    static void mult(int coef, List<Integer> l){

      for(int i: l ){
      System.out.println(i * coef);

    }
}
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> listOfIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfIntegers.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,4,2,7,5));
        mult(2,listOfIntegers);
    }
}
```